# In which of the following domains is there a primitive function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I am trying to understand in which of the following domains (no one of them is also option) there might be a primitive function to the function $$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}}-\frac{1}{z-1}
$$

A. $\{z \mid \operatorname{Re}(z)<1 / 2\} \setminus\{0\}$

B. $\{z \mid \operatorname{Re}(z)>1 / 2\} \setminus\{1\}$

C. $\{z\mid 2<|z|<3\}$

First, I can say that the problem is every region that includes $|z|=1$ only, since the residue around this singular point ($z=1$) is not zero. On the other hand, the residue of the singular point $z=0$ is zero. So according the the residue theorem, I think that even if the origin is in my domain it should not be a problem (Is this argument true?).

Second, Option $C$ is not a simply connected domain, and I can take a path around $z=1$, so C is not true.

I would like to hear your opinions about A and B.

Comment: For option C, mentioning that it is not simply connected does not add to the argument; the path around $z = 1$ is enough. Moreover, it *is* possible to have a domain that is not simply connected for which the function has a primitive, just not *that one*.

Comment: @shoteyes I understand, you right. what about my argument that including the origin in the domain should not be a problem? is it valid?

Comment: That the residue there is $0$ only tells us that a small enough *punctured* disk around that point could serve as the domain of a primitive. For a disk without a puncture (i.e., one that includes $0$) to work, the function would need a removable singularity there, but that is not the case.

Comment: @shoteyes, I do not understand your argument. the poles of the function is on zero and 1.but we can take a domain for example the unit circle and we get that there is a primitive function there due to the residue theorem

Comment: If there were a primitive for $f$ on an open set that includes $0$, then $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$ would exist and be finite. That does not happen here, so this is not possible.

Comment: @shoteyes So now I am confused. On the one hand by the residue theorem, the line integral on $f$ should be equal to the sum of the residue's of the laurent series around it's singularity points, wich happen to be zero in this specific case as long as we take a domain wich is not include's the singularity $z=1$.
on the other hand we know that if the line integral is equal to zero for every path in a specific domain, this means $f$ has primitive in this domain.
where do I wrong?

Comment: When I think of that, $z^{-n}$ also has primitive for every $n >1$ and the limit in zero does not exist

Comment: Yes, but the primitive of $z^{-n}$ for $n > 1$ is not defined for $z = 0$. I think you are applying the residue theorem incorrectly.